# Redshift Truncate table and reset Identity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I know in PostgresQL there is

```sql
truncate table restart identity;
```

but this doesn't work in Redshift. Is there something else to do this in Redshift? Otherwise I see it lot of pain to drop table and recreate and load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to reseed identity value in redshift like other sql databases. you have to create new table and move data there.