# Which one is more performant in redshift - Truncate followed with Insert Into or Drop and Create Table As?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have been working on AWS Redshift and kind of curious about which of the data loading (full reload) method is more performant.

Approach 1 (Using Truncate):

1. Truncate the existing table
2. Load the data using Insert Into Select statement

Approach 2 (Using Drop and Create):

1. Drop the existing table
2. Load the data using Create Table As Select statement

We have been using both in our ETL, but I am interested in understanding what's happening behind the scene on AWS side.

In my opinion - Drop and Create Table As statement should be more performant as it reduces the overhead of scanning/handling associated data blocks for table needed in Insert Into statement.
Moreover, truncate in AWS Redshift does not reseed identity columns - [Redshift Truncate table and reset Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64530857/redshift-truncate-table-and-reset-identity)

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Thank you @MarkB for the suggestion! I have not been able to find a significant difference in performance between these 2 approaches, so wanted to understand what's happening on the Redshift side in each method.

Comment: That said, drop and create table seems to be slightly faster in many instances. But not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redshift operates on 1MB blocks as the base unit of storage and coherency.  When changes are made to a table it is these blocks that are "published" for all to see when the changes are committed.  A table is just a list (data structure) of block ids that compose it and since there can be many versions of a table in flight at any time (if it is being changed while others are viewing it).

For the sake of the is question let's assume that the table in question is large (contains a lot of data) which I expect is true.  These two statements end up doing a common action - unlinking and freeing all the blocks in the table.  The blocks is where all the data exists so you'd think that the speed of these two are the same and on idle systems they are close.  Both automatically commit the results so the command doesn't complete until the work is done.  In this idle system comparison I've seen DROP run faster but then you need to CREATE the table again so there is time needed to recreate the data structure of the table but this can be in a transaction block so do we need to include the COMMIT?  The bottom line is that in the idle system these two approaches are quite close in runtime and when I last measured them out for a client the DROP approach was a bit faster.  I would advise you to read on before making your decision.

However, in the real world Redshift clusters are rarely idle and in loaded cases these two statements can be quite different.  DROP requires exclusive control over the table since it does not run inside of a transaction block.  All other uses of the table must be closed (committed or rolled-back) before DROP can execute.  So if you are performing this DROP/recreate procedure on a table others are using the DROP statement will be blocked until all these uses complete.  This can take an in-determinant amount of time to happen.  For ETL processing on "hidden" or "unpublished" tables the DROP/recreate method can work but you need to be really careful about what other sessions are accessing the table in question.

Truncate does run inside of a transaction but performs a commit upon completion.  This means that it won't be blocked by others working with the table.  It's just that one version of the table is full (for those who were looking at it before truncate ran) and one version is completely empty.  The data structure of the table has versions for each session that has it open and each sees the blocks (or lack of blocks) that corresponds to their version.  I suspect that it is managing these data structures and propagating these changes through the commit queue that slows TRUNCATE down slightly - bookkeeping.  The upside for this bookkeeping is that TRUNCATE will not be blocked by other sessions reading the table.

The deciding factors on choosing between these approaches is often not performance, it is which one has the locking and coherency features that will work in your solution.

Comment: Thank you so much @billweiner for amazing explanation! It makes a lot of sense. And to your questions, this method of loading the data would be used to create the intermediate tables helping build up the data to be inserted into the final table. So, usually no one would be directly accessing these tables. So, don't have to worry about sessions locking the table. It's more for finding a way with less overhead on the system.

Comment: Final tables then will be loaded either using Delete/Insert in case of incremental load or Alter Table Rename with staging table in case of full data refresh.